# Wide range and high precision current measurement

Tags: current-measurement, shunt, precision

I need to measure current over a large range from a few µA up to 2A. The application is sensitive to noise at later calculations with the measured current. My idea is to use different shunt resistors which are bypassed as needed.

Has anyone some experience with this situation and has already selected a bypass switch for that purpose? My first idea is to use a simple bistable relay but I don't know how much that would affect noise behaviour on low current measurement.

Comment: What resolution do you actually need and do you need it over the full range?

Comment: For wide range measurements I have used a current mirror with a voltage controlled output gain stage.

Comment: How much noise can you tolerate? What precision do you need? How fast do you need to measure? All of these things have a bearing on how you should implement this. The switch you choose is more likely to introduce offset and drift errors than noise. @PeterSmith can you elaborate on your current mirror solution?

Comment: at what rate do you need the samples? if slow enough, you can  feed an RC with a shunt and using timing to measure instead of voltage.

Comment: I already picked an AD converter which makes up to 500k samples per second but speed is not the problem here. I could live with much slower values. Unfortunately the accuracy is needed at the full range.

Comment: If this is a general purpose solution where you don't know what the maximum voltage could be, you need to protect the larger value shunts from burning up if the wrong range is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bypassing a current shunt requires an impractically low resistance switch, when the currents start to get into the amps.

Far better is a current routing switch as shown below. Each switch element can now be any resistance without affecting the metering accuracy, it only affects the voltage drop across the meter. This means you can choose (for instance) a power FET for SW1, and an analogue multiplexer for SW3 and SW4. You could even use BJTs, which would not work at all well as low resistance switches, but work just fine for current steering.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1AXjo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Reed relay is even better for low noise.

Comment: @LongPham reed relays are worth considering, but you have to look at all their specs. Hot switching is not great for instance, if that's important in the final application.

Comment: The series resistance to the opamp input on the highest current setting will cause offset errors and make the current noise worse. Would it be better to switch the +ve input to different points in the chain rather than switching the current path?

Comment: @Loganf The input current path must be switched. The amplifier could be switched to the same point as well, if you really think the extra resistance of R4 is significant. Not doing so saves an analogue multiplexer. Perhaps you'd work out for me, and reply in the next comment, what the additional offset and current noise is from a 90ohm R4, or even a 90k R7, when using something like a TL074 or a LMC6482 as the follower.

Comment: @niel_uk taking your 90k R7, and assuming 5pA/rtHz (which is pretty good for an opamp), you get 450nV/rtHz, or 142uVrms for a bandwidth of 100kHz.(nearly 1mv peak). This translates to a 100uA error when your R6 is in circuit (for 10k shunt). Maybe that level of error is okay? This didn't include the shunt resistor noise or opamp voltage noise etc etc.

Comment: No that's wrong, 1mV on 10k  is 100nA. Sorry. But 1 10k resistor is likely for uA range so it's significant I think

Comment: @Loganf How about you go look up the current noise for the two opamps I specified? I don't know which opamp you're quoting 5pA for, the two I specified do 10fA and 30fA respectively. 100kHz is quite a wide bandwidth to be working with for a current measurement. A specification as significant as that should be mentioned up front in the question. I tend to measure current, well DC current at least, in Hz. It's what I've built for my bench DMM current measurement range, and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: @Loganf although looking at a few other amps, 5534 is a better noise match to 10k, with 3.5nV and 400fA noise. The superb OPA211 at 1.1nV 1.7pA really needs a low resistance, ratio of noises 650 ohms. But I'd bought a load of LMC6482s for general purpose low voltage R2R use, so that's what I used. Even if I plugged in some 5532s with the 10k current shunt resistance, I doubt that I would see a major difference.

Comment: @neil_uk 100kHz was a guess based on the op saying "later calculations" so I assumed it was part of a system rather than a standalone multimeter. The 5pA comes from looking at bjt input stage op amps for lower voltage noise. The 2 opamps you mentioned have 18nV and 37nV respectively, being jfet input stages. OPA211 is more what I was thinking of. Either way, I don't know how stringent the requirements are, but if they need a few uA on a 2A measurement then the op amp choice and resistor arrangement are equally important. Not so if you can get away with slow measurements or low precision.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the schematic of TX3 multimeter to see how Tek did this.

https://www.tek.com/manual/tx1-and-tx3-service-manual

Comment: I took a look at the manual and it seems they use three shunts and route the current through a mosfet.

Comment: Indeed it does. My point: TEK know what they are doing. It is a good arrangement to copy - it is protected against abuse to a high level, and Clearly works OK, these meters have 100nA resolution.

Comment: Good solution. Is the fuse 2A? There seems to be a risk of burning up the 50 ohm resistor if the voltage is high and the wrong scale is selected. Maybe the firmware is fast enough to change scales before this happens. Note that Neil's solution has the same potential issue.